# How to group by a column with duplicate values while pulling all associated columns in table with SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 5 columns:

```
Party_ID | Site_ID | Party_Name | Group_Num | Code
---------+---------+------------+-----------+-----
123         A3D       MSFT        092079177   04
212         B5C       MSFT        092079177   05
313         S4F       MSFT        828539556   08
314         G3B       MSFT        828434232   09
515         KM9       MSFT        022901486   10
616         NM5       MSFT        022901486   09
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Party_ID | Site_ID | Party_Name | Group_Num | Code | Count
---------+---------+------------+-----------+------+--------
123         A3D       MSFT        092079177   04      12
212         B5C       MSFT        092079177   05      2
313         S4F       MSFT        828539556   08      3
314         G3B       MSFT        828434232   09      1 
515         KM9       MSFT        022901486   10      2
```

I would like to group by 'Group_Num' which is a 9-digit value per row while pulling all associated fields data with it as a new table. There are duplicate values in Group_Num but are paired to unique values in other fields.

New to SQL and using Snowflake. I currently have this to count number of occurrences Group_Num has given Party_ID in query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM F1_TABLE 
GROUP BY PARTY_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Group_Num) > 1)
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Group_Num) DESC;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Updated data I'm working with. Sorry.

Comment: I think the desired outcome is needed here.  Not understanding what you want to accomplish by deduping AND retaining non-duplicated data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, not sure if you want to end up with a completely deduped table or not, but this window function + `QUALIFY` allow you to choose a record to keep for each dupe:

```
SELECT *
FROM F1_TABLE
QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Group_Num ORDER BY Party_ID) = 1;
```

This example chooses the first Party_ID, but you can choose whatever you want (or let Snowflake choose for you by excluding the `ORDER BY` clause.

If this isn't what you are looking for, can you please provide what your resulting table would look like in your question?

Comment: I am trying to create the output table (was able to generate the table in R with a count field that shows many times the Group_Num showed up). Thanks for being patient - working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but if all you want is the 1st table with a count of Group Num appended to it then just do the count in a subquery and join to it e.g.

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.COUNTER
FROM F1_TABLE T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Group_Num, COUNT(1) AS COUNTER
            FROM F1_TABLE
            GROUP BY Group_Num) AS T2
ON T1.GROUP_NUM = T2.GROUP_NUM
```

If you are trying to dedupe the main table in some way, as well, then do a SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY